# Load <head> </head> content from external page, specifically the stylesheets from the external page

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have been trying to solution this for quite some time now. I have had a unique request from a friend to help them build a webpage that dynamically pulls a div tag from an external page (different server) so that when that page updates, it updates on this page. I solved that by utilizing jquery's .load to specify the .div to pull in, but the styling does not flow in as well since it does not reside within the div tag itself, but within the  tags. So, I am trying to figure out how I can pull in the  content, specifically the stylesheets if at all possible, from the other page and place it in the  tags of my page.

I am at a loss on this and I would really appreciate some help.

Here is my page setup as I have it this moment:

proxy.php (pulls external page in)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<base target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $url = 'www.EXAMPLE.com/';
    $htm = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $htm;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Actual page to display specific content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> - Products</title>
<?php 
$file = file_get_contents("proxy.php");
$head = preg_replace("#(.*)<head>(.*?)</head>(.*)#is", '$2', $file);
echo $head;
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="contentWrapper">
<div id="contentMain">
<script>
$("#contentMain").load("proxy.php #content");
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->
</html>
```

Comment: awh man.. I don't know where to start here..

Comment: I think you and your friend should rethink this system. It's messy. If you pull in the stylesheet, you then need to consider whether or not there are any inline styles affecting the divs, etc. I think a better way would be to use an iframe. It would be much less fuss and guaranteed to work.

Comment: iframe would work to an extent, but it will not do the final piece (this is where I ran into the headache). I cannot only pull a div forward from the external site - I have to pull the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cURL version of `file_get_contents` for remote files because `allow_url_fopen` most likely isn't set on your host's server for security reasons.

```
function curl_file_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $curlError = curl_errno($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    // Return result if we don't have errors, if there is a result, and if we have a 200 OK
    if (!$curlError && $result && $status == '200') {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$stylesheet = curl_file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/css/style.css');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($stylesheet);
echo "</pre>";
```